# How to test fileupload using SOAP UI

Tags: java, soap, file-upload, webservice-client

How to  test fileupload using SOAP UI.

There is a service which accepts file as input
I want to simulate that using SOAP UI
It gives me .

content should be inline .

[image]

Comment: This question is basically impossible to answer in its present form. You need to supply more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some docs on using attachments in soapUI.

http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/adding-headers-and-attachments.html

From Ole in the eviware forum

1. Create a new Project
2. Create a TestSuite in the Project
3. Create a TestCase in the TestSuite
4. Add an HTTP TestRequest Step to the TestCase

   - Set the endpoint to the URL you want to upload to
   - Set the method to POST (or PUT)
5. In the Request Editor add the File you want to upload to the Attachments tab
6. Set the Media-Type of the POST Body to the same as the Content-Type of the attached File
7. Send the request!

Comment: i think attachment and doc as param to method are different